# Can I edit an iPad photo and save both the edited and original version?

Tags: ipad, photos, photo-stream, camera-roll

I have an iPad 2 running iOS 8. Is there a way to edit a photo and save both the edited and original versions? Does it matter if I make the edit from the photo stream or camera roll? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a screenshot of the photo by pressing the home button and power putton together.

After this you can edit one of those photo's